# Solve: $\tan\frac x2 = x,\> x\in(0,\pi)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate the shortest distance between two points on a sphere in terms of its radius and the angle they intend at the centre. I'm stuck at the equation: 
$$\tan(x/2) = x,\ 0<x<\pi$$

I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Except for $x=0$ the solutions to this equation cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: $x=0$ works.  And there are infinitely many other solutions.

Comment: I graphed y=x and y=tan(x/2) on a graphing calculator and they intersect at around 2.3, so I'm a bit confused when you say it has no solution. Im looking for an exact mathematical solution  though, not the graphical one.

Comment: @DhruvaNaik I did not say that the equation has no solution. I said that the solutions (except for the trivial one) cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. But of course you can find them numerically, and for large $|x|$ the consecutive solutions will differ by $\approx\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that there is no analytic solution, an approximate close-form may be desirable. Recognizing that the root within $(0,\pi)$ is near $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, let $f (x) = x\cot\frac x2 -1$ and approximate the root $r$ as

$$ 0= f(r) = f(\frac{3\pi}{4})+ f’(\frac{3\pi}{4})(r-\frac{3\pi}{4})$$

Solve to obtain

$$r= \frac{16+8\sqrt2-9\pi^2}{8\sqrt2-12\pi}= 2,3313$$

vs. the exact numerical root $2.3311$

Answer (score 0):

As this transcendental equation cannot be solved analytically,
iteration is resorted to.

In Newton's method the amount to be subtracted for successive root approximation is, if $\tan x/2=t,$

$$ \dfrac{\tan x/2-x}{\frac12 \sec^2 x/2- 1}$$

$$ x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\dfrac{2(t-x)}{t^2-1},$$

when you can start at any value near enough to the expected root.

There are numerous roots. Asymptotic approximation can be seen by graphing.. to tend to odd multiples of $(2 k -1)\pi.$